# Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'

Tags: mysql

Me sale este error y no sé como solucionarlo.

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061 "Unknown error")

Comment: cómo es tu cadena de conexión? o en que parte se genera ese error?

Comment: eso parece workbench

Comment: no puedo ingresar de xampp a su consola para cargar una base de datos, intente ingresar mediante la consola de windows y cuando le di enter despues de escribir el comando y pasar por alto el password ya que no tengo ni una contraseña me salio ese error

Comment: y esta funcionando el mysql???

Comment: estas entrando desde el mismo equipo u otro de forma remota?

Comment: busca skip-networking en my.cnf y comentalo...

Comment: estoy entrando desde el mismo equipo 
estoy usando xampp e ise lebantar el apache y mysql ya cambie los puertos pero cuando ingreso a consola para cargar base de datos pues me sale todo eso

Comment: ok lo buscare gracias :V